# Refreshing the state from the database only if there is a change in the database in react redux application

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

In my react redux application, I use `useEffect` to load data from the database. I have the `props.data === null` check to load data only if it has not been loaded already. That is, in the first visit, the data from the database will be fetched, but in the subsequent visits no database call is made. However, with this approach, I cannot keep the local state 100% up-to-date since there might be changes in the data. I wonder how can I refresh the state from the database only if there is a change in the database in react redux application. Any ideas?

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (props.loading == false) {
            if(props.data === null)
                props.fetchData(id)
    }
}, [])
```

Answer (score 2):

Talking to the database is usually a one way thing. You won't know if data has changed until you ask the database.

If you can figure out how often your data is going to change on average, you can call your fetchData method on an interval to refresh it every so often.

Here is an example that calls fetchData every two seconds.

```js
function useInterval(callback, delay) {
  const savedCallback = React.useRef();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    savedCallback.current = callback;
  });

  React.useEffect(() => {
    function tick() {
      savedCallback.current();
    }

    let id = setInterval(tick, delay);
    return () => clearInterval(id);
  }, [delay]);
}

const averageDataRefreshDelay = 2 * 1000 // 2 seconds

const App = props => {
  const { fetchData } = props;
  useInterval(fetchData, averageDataRefreshDelay);
  
  return (
    <div>Your component</div>
   )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App fetchData={ () => console.log('... fetching data ...') } />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```